# Nesting columns good practice?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am unable to find any rules as to whether or not this is something that should be done. Bootstrap clearly outlines amongst its rules the following:

- Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
  .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding
- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns
- Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
  immediate children of rows

So from this I conclude that each section of the website that I do want self-contained would have a `container` class. Within this we'd have a `row` and within that we'd have a `column`. Like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">COL 1 of 2</div>
        <div class="col">COL 2 of 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is, the rules specify that **only columns may be immediate children of rows** but it doesn't say what the children of columns should be. If I was to want to "nest" another set of double columns within another column, would I write it like in case one or case two?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">  <!--Columns within columns without a row-->
            <div class="col"> 
            <div class="col">
        </div>
        <div class="col">  <!--Row nested before nesting columns-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"> 
                <div class="col">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Both work in terms of actually making the page, but I do not know what is considered "good practice". There are obviously limitations to both ways of writing things. In my case, I'd want the "column" to be filled with a dynamically generated amount of elements, which on different screen resolutions/responsive sizes would be aligned, so a row wrapper is not an option. I do not know how many elements per row I'd have, which would make the following rows break and wrap when it is not needed.

So, is it okay to nest columns within columns without a row to hold the children?

Comment: _"If I was to want to "nest" another set of double columns within another column, would I write it like in case one or case two?"_ Case 2

Comment: Explained in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: @ZimSystem the docs explain that you nest rows in columns and always in this switch `row` / `col` manner, but I need to nest a column within a column, without a row. Is this acceptable?

Comment: It's not "acceptable" because as explained "add a new .row and set of columns within an existing column". cols should always be the direct child of a row because of negative margins and padding.

Comment: I misinterpreted that text I guess. The statement "only cols are immediate children of row" however does not restrict cols to have cols as their own children. I do not get the whole negative margins/padding thing though.

Comment: @ZimSystem what about this though:

https://www.bootply.com/T6CrevHsTh

Obviously I do not want to have it aligned as shown, but since the amount of "columns" is dynamically generated, how do I go about making them align properly, and with responsiveness it becomes even worse, I'd have to switch from having 3 rows (3x3) to having 4x2 +1 to having 9 x 1 rows. Because columns go from being `col-md-4` to `col-xs-12`. How to solve that because I cannot swap them around within HTML on screen resizes

Comment: The negative margin in the row "resets" the column's padding. If you don't use another row, each group of child columns will creep inward: https://www.codeply.com/go/aV4kCASGc8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested rows are better semantically and in some edge cases to maintain the design. This is however opinion but opinion that's based on best practice.

I'd put the row before for the column just to be clear on your intent and to make it more modular.

It's best to think about it as a module and ask yourself "Can I lift this section of markup out of its position and put it anywhere else on the page and it still hold its form?" By encapsulating it within a row, you can answer yes to that question. Of course its always a battle between only putting in mark-up that is necessary and being modular but with concepts such as SMACSS, Object Oriented CSS etc... taking the lead in how we think about structuring our markup and CSS its seems consensus is with a bit of extra markup in order to maintain modularization.

Comment: I think you made a `boo boo` in that HTML code there, I already did "add the extra row" in the example that I added to the main post thus making it modular. If I get you correctly it is semantically better to keep columns within rows and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Not used to writing code in stackoverflow. Yes. It's better to keep columns within rows and be done with it. Again, that is opinionated however and be aware that some disagree. I really prefer, Jonathan Snook's way of maintaining css and html (author of SMACSS) and one of the first things he does is draw containers around all of this mark-up at the cost of extra div's in order to maintain modularity. Hope it helps.

Comment: What happens if the content is dynamic though, take a look at this: https://www.bootply.com/T6CrevHsTh All the columns are within a row, but the behaviour should not be as shown

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you want the final design to look like. Are you wanting all of the colored boxes to float and wrap without the spacing? Or do you have the option of stacking the boxes? With the caveat of not knowing what the goal is and if you have the option of using flexbox, I would create my own class within the row and use flexbox wrap which would tidily wrap all of divs properly. If you don't need it to wrap then I would wrap every 3rd col-md-3 div in another row which would clear them in groups and further modularize the groups. Not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: It should look something along the lines of this: http://imgur.com/a/cNtgG This issue is, I know that 3 rows would make this a breeze, but there is neither a finite number of elements (9 in this example) nor a specific number of elements per row being handled, because as responsive design kicks in, the columns switch from being `col-md-4` to `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-12` to make it mobile friendly. And if we were to say, have 3 per row, once it swaps to `col-sm-6` there would be a `gap` left for the 4th element, which should be filled by another column. Row groups make it impossible.

Comment: If you add the class myCustomClass to the row in the bootply example and then add this to the css. .myCustomClass{ display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}, I think that will give you want you are looking for in terms of appearance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145892/discussion-between-joshua-maddox-and-dellirium).

Answer (score 3):

You should put any nested `.row`s inside of a `.container` to contain the negative margins, and only nest a `.col` inside of a `.row`:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col">  <!--Row nested before nesting columns-->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"> </div>
                <div class="col"> </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- .container -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Having a container doesn't solve the issue, it further enhances it. The question is not `how to nest a row in a column` rather `is nesting a set of columns within a column WITHOUT a row okay?` I know it is doable, but I do not know if I should do it. And I do not want my `inner columns` to be grouped into rows

Comment: And I answered: "only nest a .col inside of a .row." http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting